# How would I make a pixel search and set cursor position at x,y

Tags: c#

As the title describes I'm wondering how to create a simple pixel search function that'll find a specified color pixel and use a Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y); For example, if I was looking for a certain type of greenish color on google earth the pixel searcher would scan for the color. NOTE: In addition to this I've already created a random movement function that'll randomly offset the direction. I just can't seem to get the color pixel search wrapped around my head. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: I haven't had any luck in finding anything that could lead me in the right direction. The only thing I've been using is an image search tutorial found on YouTube, but it doesn't always work. Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEgxZrXPnzc

Comment: You need to put whatever image you are wanting to scan in a Bitmap and start checking pixel by pixel. If you want to scan portions of your screen then you need to grab a screenshot of the screen or area of the screen and put that into the Bitmap. You could also just scan pixel by pixel on the screen but I believe it will be much slower, but doable. You need to look into some winapi for this (dllimport)